# Null pointer exception in passing checkbox value

Tags: java, jdbc, checkbox

I made an index page in which you take the value of checkbox and pass it on to a file named AddToWork.java but it is showing null pointer exception. There is some problem in passing the value of the checkbox. Kindly help. Here is the code snipped for index page

```
<td>
<center>
<form action="addtowork?id2=<%=mail.getTempToken()%>" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Add to my work">
<input type="checkbox" name="flag" value="flag">High Priority</form>   
</center></td>
```

for AddToWork.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    EmailDesc mail = new EmailDesc();

    String imp = new String();

    imp = (String) request.getParameter("flag");



    String thisid = request.getParameter("id2");
    Home home = new Home();

    User user = new User();

    user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");

    mail = home.getEmail(thisid, user);



    home.givePermanentToken(mail,thisid);

    if (imp.equals("flag")){
        System.out.println("Priority Changed to " + mail.getPriority() + "!");
    }



    response.sendRedirect("index1.jsp");



}
```

If I remove the if statement in addtowork.java, the code runs perfectly.

Comment: `request.getParameter("flag")` is somehow coming as null, then doing ` if (imp.equals("flag"))` is actually causing `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1: name.equals("Java") Compare unknown value with known value.**

We are comparing `name(unknown)` value with another string `Java(known)` value. name will be decided based on some database call, calling another method, etc... It may possible you get null value of name and possible chances of `java.lang.NullPointerException` or you have to check explicitly for null value of name.

**Case 2: "Java".equals(name) Compare known value with unknown value.**

We are comparing `Java(known)` value with another string `name(unknown)` value. Same way name will be decided based on some database call, calling another method, etc... But `equals` and `equalsIgnoreCase` method of String will handle the `null` value and you don't have to check explicitly for null value of name.

In your case

```
/* You are getting `null` for variable `imp` */
imp = (String) request.getParameter("flag");
```

Change

```
if (imp.equals("flag")){
    System.out.println("Priority Changed to " + mail.getPriority() + "!");
}
```

to

```
if ("flag".equals(imp)){
    System.out.println("Priority Changed to " + mail.getPriority() + "!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the concept! :)

Answer (score 2):

it is because your "imp" Object is pointing to nothing (null) & it is throwing an exception. use "Yoda notation" like so

```
if("flag".equals(imp)){
     // your code
}
```

this removes the possibility of getting a null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

Case I : When you are submitting the form with checking the check box , it will work because the value is set in request parameter `flag`

Case II : When you are submitting the form without checking the "priority" check box then the request parameter sets to null and later you calling the equal method on null on if condition. so please use

```
if("flag".equals(imp))
```

Note :- It's bad practice to create string using new

```
String imp = new String(); //bad don't use this
String imp = ""; //use in this way
```